# Send post and get request at the same time in VOLLEY

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-volley

I have a recyclerview which I show my values for users. But I need to show their own values to them.

First this is the code for GET values. (Working perfectly)

```
 private void loadValues() {

    StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, urlUpload, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            try {
                JSONArray values =new JSONArray(response);
                for (int i = 0; i < values.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object=values.getJSONObject(i);

                    int id =object.getInt("id");
                    int user_id=object.getInt("user_id");

                    String department=object.getString("department");
                    String description=object.getString("description");
                    String address=object.getString("address");
                    String addressdesc=object.getString("addressdesc");
                    String lattitude=object.getString("lattitude");
                    String longitude=object.getString("longitude");
                    String image=object.getString("image");
                    String state=object.getString("state");

                    Modelmodel=new Model(id,user_id,department,description,address,addressdesc,lattitude,longitude,image,state);
                    recyclerList.add(model);
                }
                adapter=new Adapter(UserRecords.this,recyclerList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            Toast.makeText(UserRecords.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String,String> params =new HashMap<>();
            params.put("user_id","4");  // 4 is just for now. it should return 3 values from sql.
            return params;
        }
    } ; 
    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(stringRequest);

}
```

And that's my PHP script for GET. And it's working perfectly fine too. When I try  `$user_id2 =4;`
it returns values to me.

```
<?php 

 //  $user_id2  =  $_POST['user_id'];
 require_once 'connect.php';
 mysqli_query($conn,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");

 //Checking if any error occured while connecting
 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 die();
 }

 //creating a query

 $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT records.id, records.user_id, parameters.p_name AS department, records.description, 
 records.address, records.addressdesc, records.lattitude, records.longitude, records.image, records.state 
 from records,parameters WHERE parameters.p_id=records.department AND parameters.group_id=
 (SELECT groups.id FROM groups where groups.group_name = 'department') AND records.user_id = '$user_id2'");

 //executing the query 
 $stmt->execute();

 //binding results to the query 
 $stmt->bind_result($id,$user_id,$department,$description,$address,$addressdesc,
 $lattitude,$longitude,$image,$state);

 $records = array(); 

 //traversing through all the result 
 while($stmt->fetch()){
 $temp = array();
 $temp['id'] = $id; 
 $temp['user_id'] = $user_id; 
 $temp['department'] = $department; 
 $temp['description'] = $description; 
 $temp['address'] = $address; 
 $temp['addressdesc'] = $addressdesc; 
 $temp['lattitude'] = $lattitude; 
 $temp['longitude'] = $longitude; 
 $temp['image'] = $image; 
 $temp['state'] = $state; 
 array_push($records, $temp);
 }

 //displaying the result in json format 
 echo json_encode($records);
```

I did POST request before GET request on Android but it didn't work. 
If you look end of my SQL code, you will see `records.user_id = '$user_id2'`. I need to get user_id2 value with POST request, then I need to give this value to the SQL. Then I will make get request and it will show peoples own values in the recyclerview.

Briefly: I need to send post my user_id to PHP then use it in SQL then return values with get method to Android.

Comment: You're using prepared statements but are still injecting variables directly into the SQL string?  That completely defeats the purpose of prepared statements!  You're wide open to SQL injection attacks unless you use prepared statements properly.  http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Whats the prepared statements ? I just inject values to sql when people create a request or something. Why this is bad ? In this example : i post user_id to the php, and getting values from database for android program.

Comment: It's bad because I could craft a payload that instead of fetching record 3 ```?id=3``` could delete your database ```?id=3); DROP TABLE records; --``` and that's just for starters.  Read the website I linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry i just saw something in Request.Method .

I didnt change anything in this code , only i changed Request.Method.GET   to Request.Method.DEPRECATED_GET_OR_POST

I just saw this method now. So its working perfectly.